# Boost serialization, loading an archived class by base type gives wrong data

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

I wrote an example program to figure out Boost's serialization library before I implemented it into a project, however, I got some unexplained behavior.

---

In my example, I had two classes: a generic `BaseClass` and a specialized `DerivedClass` (analogous to what I plan to use Boost for). `BaseClass` only has one member, a string called `name`, which defaults to "BaseClass". `DerivedClass` publicly inherits `BaseClass`, sets `name` to something else and has its own unique member, `data`.

In the main program, I create a `DerivedClass` with `data` set to "special cool stuff", and a `BaseClass` with `name` "regular stuff". I write both of these to a file with `boost::archive::text_oarchive`, and read the first object, the `DerivedClass`, back twice (recreating the `std::ifstream` both times). The first time reading it back, I put it to a `BaseClass*`. Calling `BaseClass::printData()` (a virtual method that prints the `std::typeid` and  `name`) prints something along the lines of:

```
 --- Storage done, now loading the first object as BaseClass --- 
9BaseClass: 0
```

Next, when I load it as a `DerivedClass*` and call `DerivedClass::printData()` (which is overridden from `BaseClass` to include the member `data` in the output) correctly prints:

```
 --- Storage done, now loading the first object as DerivedClass --- 
12DerivedClass: DerivedClass AND special cool stuff
```

Looking in the file I'm writing to, I see this:

```
22 serialization::archive 15 0 1 0
0 1 0
1 12 DerivedClass 18 special cool stuff 1
2 13 regular stuff
```

And when I call `BaseClass::printData()` on the original, pre-serializing `DerivedClass`, I get this:

```
9BaseClass: DerivedClass
```

Obviously, the `DerivedClass` is being stored correctly. Something about loading it as a `BaseClass` to check `name` is messing up. I cannot think of why it would give me a `std::string` containing `0`.

I'm just starting to learn how to use this library, and most of the similar questions and documentation I've found online have no effect (ie, using `BOOST_EXPORT_CLASS` or `BOOST_CLASS_TYPE_INFO`, although it could very well be I was using them incorrectly).

---

Here is my code:

### main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/nvp.hpp>

#include "baseclass.h"
#include "derivedclass.h"

int main() {
    BaseClass*  testBase = new BaseClass("regular stuff");
    DerivedClass* testDerivate = new DerivedClass("special cool stuff");

    testDerivate->BaseClass::printData();

    std::cout << std::endl << " --- " << "Storing objects in the file 'output'..." << " --- " << std::endl;

    std::ofstream output("storage");

    {
        boost::archive::text_oarchive boost_out(output);
        boost_out << (testDerivate);
        testDerivate->printData();
        boost_out << (testBase);
        testBase->printData();
    }

    std::cout << std::endl << " --- " << "Storage done, now loading the first object as BaseClass" << " --- " << std::endl;

    {
        std::ifstream input("storage");
        BaseClass*  base;
        boost::archive::text_iarchive boost_in(input);
        boost_in >> (base);
        base->printData();
        input.close();
    }

    std::cout << std::endl << " --- " << "Storage done, now loading the first object as DerivedClass" << " --- " << std::endl;

    {
        std::ifstream input("storage");
        DerivedClass* derive;
        boost::archive::text_iarchive boost_in(input);
        boost_in >> (derive);
        derive->printData();
        input.close();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

### baseclass.h

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

#include <boost/serialization/access.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/nvp.hpp>

class BaseClass
{
public:
    BaseClass() {
        name = "BaseClass";
    }

    BaseClass(std::string custom) {
        name = custom;
    }

    virtual ~BaseClass() {}

    virtual void printData() {
        std::cout << typeid(*this).name() << ": " << name << std::endl;   
    }

protected:
    std::string name;

private:    
    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version) {
        ar & (name);
    }
};
```

### derivedclass.hpp

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

#include <boost/serialization/base_object.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/access.hpp>

#include "baseclass.h"

class DerivedClass :  public BaseClass
{
public:
    DerivedClass() : BaseClass("DerivedClass") {}
    DerivedClass(std::string custom) : BaseClass("DerivedClass") {
        data = custom;
    }

    virtual ~DerivedClass() {}

    void printData() override {
        std::cout << typeid(*this).name() << ": " << name << " AND " << data << std::endl;
    }

protected:
    std::string data;

private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version) {
        ar & (boost::serialization::base_object<BaseClass>(*this));
        ar & (data);
    }
};
```

---

Sorry if this is a bit long, I wanted to be as descriptive as possible. I'm very new to using Boost and I'm not all that experienced with C++, so even if you just have some general comments on my code, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not loading the same *types* as you're serializing.

So, while **can** say:

```
Base* b = new Derived();
boost_out << b;
```

And deserialize with:

```
Base* b = nullptr;
boost_in >> b;
```

You **cannot** serialize a `Derived*` and deserialize it as `Base*` or vice versa.

So, if you know the receiving code must support all derived classes, make it explicit and serialize a `Base*`.

### EXPORT the Types

To let the de-serializing end know what the possible set of derived types is that could be encountered in deserializing a polymorphic base pointer, export the types.

- https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/serialization/doc/traits.html#export
- also see https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/serialization/doc/special.html#export:

  > Including `BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT` in the "a.hpp" header itself as one would do with other serialization traits will make it difficult or impossible to follow the rule above regarding inclusion of archive headers before `BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT` is invoked. This can best be addressed by using `BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_KEY` in the header declarations and `BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_IMPLEMENT` in the class definition file.
  >
  > [ ... snip ... ]
  >
  > Placing `BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT` in library code will **have no effect unless archive class headers are also included**. So when building a library, one should include all headers for all the archive classes which he anticipates using. Alternatively, one can include headers for just the Polymoprhic *[sic]* Archives.

### DEMO

See it **<kbd>[Live On Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Yk5thdMBdwpRSac7)</kbd>**

- main.cpp

  ```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <fstream>
  #include <string>

  #include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
  #include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
  #include <boost/serialization/nvp.hpp>
  //#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>

  #include "baseclass.h"
  #include "derivedclass.h"

  int main() {
      BaseClass* testBase = new BaseClass("regular stuff");
      BaseClass* testDerived = new DerivedClass("special cool stuff");

      std::cout << std::endl << " --- " << "Storing objects in the file 'output'..." << " --- " << std::endl;

      {
          std::ofstream output("storage");
          boost::archive::text_oarchive boost_out(output);
          boost_out << testBase << testDerived;
      }

      std::cout << std::endl << " --- " << "Storage done, now loading the first object as BaseClass" << " --- " << std::endl;

      {
          std::ifstream input("storage");
          BaseClass* b1;
          BaseClass* b2;
          boost::archive::text_iarchive boost_in(input);
          boost_in >> b1 >> b2;

          std::cout << "b1: "; b1->printData();
          std::cout << "b2: "; b2->printData();
      }
  }
  ```
- baseclass.h

  ```
  #pragma once

  #include <string>
  #include <iostream>
  #include <typeinfo>

  #include <boost/serialization/access.hpp>
  #include <boost/serialization/nvp.hpp>
  #include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>

  class BaseClass
  {
  public:
      BaseClass() {
          name = "BaseClass";
      }

      BaseClass(std::string custom) {
          name = custom;
      }

      virtual ~BaseClass() {}

      virtual void printData() {
          std::cout << typeid(*this).name() << ": " << name << std::endl;   
      }

  protected:
      std::string name;

  private:    
      friend class boost::serialization::access;

      template<class Archive>
      void serialize(Archive & ar, unsigned) {
          ar & (name);
      }
  };

  BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_KEY2(BaseClass, "BaseClass");
  ```
- baseclass.cpp

  ```
  #include "baseclass.h"
  #include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
  #include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
  BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_IMPLEMENT(BaseClass)
  ```
- derivedclass.h

  ```
  #pragma once

  #include <string>
  #include <iostream>
  #include <typeinfo>

  #include <boost/serialization/base_object.hpp>
  #include <boost/serialization/access.hpp>
  #include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>

  #include "baseclass.h"

  class DerivedClass :  public BaseClass
  {
  public:
      DerivedClass() : BaseClass("DerivedClass") {}
      DerivedClass(std::string custom) : BaseClass("DerivedClass") {
          data = custom;
      }

      virtual ~DerivedClass() {}

      void printData() override {
          std::cout << typeid(*this).name() << ": " << name << " AND " << data << std::endl;
      }

  protected:
      std::string data;

  private:
      friend class boost::serialization::access;

      template<class Archive>
      void serialize(Archive & ar, unsigned) {
          ar & (boost::serialization::base_object<BaseClass>(*this));
          ar & (data);
      }
  };

  BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_KEY2(DerivedClass, "DerivedClass");
  ```
- derivedclass.cpp

  ```
  #include "derivedclass.h"
  #include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
  #include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
  BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_IMPLEMENT(DerivedClass)
  ```

Output:

Comment: Added demo [Live On Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Yk5thdMBdwpRSac7)